# Selecting date from Antd Datepicker using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, testing, puppeteer, end-to-end

I am writing test cases using Puppeteer. My current test case looks like this:

```
// Put Dates
await page.type('input[placeholder="Start date"]', '2021-03-01');
await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
await page.type('input[placeholder="End date"]', '2021-03-02');
await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
// Submitting form
await Promise.all([page.click('#submit')]);
done();
```

Is there anyway to not type but click or select dates from the Datepicker?

Comment: have you tried `page.click(selector)` ?